# Python mayavi : How to draw spheres at random positions in 3D space

Tags: python, mayavi.mlab

This is a code for generating random sized spheres with mayavi,

I want to make the spheres to be connected with each other by the surface or with a bond line:

1. Spheres must be at random positions in 3D space
2. Spheres must be with the same radius

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

[phi,theta] = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:12j,0:np.pi:12j]
x = np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta)
y = np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(theta)

def plot_sphere(p):
    
    r,a,b,c = p
    r=1
    return mlab.mesh(r*x+a, r*y+b, r*z )  


for k in range(8):
    c = np.random.rand(4)
    c[0] /= 10.
    plot_sphere(c)

mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just using the mayavi `points3d` function? By default the `mode` parameter is set to sphere and you can set the diameter by using the `scale_factor` parameter. You can also increase the resolution of the sphere by varying the `resolution` parameter.

Here is the code:

```
def draw_sphere(
        center_coordinates,
        radius,
        figure_title,
        color,
        background,
        foreground
):
    sphere = mlab.figure(figure_title)
    sphere.scene.background = background
    sphere.scene.foreground = foreground

    mlab.points3d(
        center_coordinates[0],
        center_coordinates[1],
        center_coordinates[2],
        color=color,
        resolution=256,
        scale_factor=2*radius,
        figure=sphere
    )
```

Regarding the *connected with each other by the surface* issue, your explanation is poor. Maybe you mean just tangent spheres, but I would need more details.

Answer (score 0):

From sphere equation:

[image]

So when passing arguments to `mlab.mesh` we would like to set `[x_0, y_0, z_0]` for each sphere such as they are at different positions from the axis.

The problem was that the numbers generated by `np.random.rand(4)` are random, but not distinct.

Let's modify so that the arguments `[x_0, y_0, z_0]` are random and distinct:

1. We use `sample` to get distinct index numbers in a cube
2. We convert using `index_to_3d` the index to an `(x, y, z)` coordinates

The radius, `r`, can be adjusted to have more or less spacing between the spheres.

***Spheres at 3D space***

Code:

```
import random
from itertools import product

from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

[phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:12j, 0:np.pi:12j]
x = np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)
y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(theta)


def plot_sphere(x_0, y_0, z_0):
    r = 0.5
    return mlab.mesh(r * x + x_0, r * y + y_0, r * z + z_0)

SPHERES_NUMBER = 200

CUBE_SIZE = 10

def index_to_3d(i, SIZE):
    z = i // (SIZE * SIZE)
    i -= (z * SIZE * SIZE)
    y = i // SIZE
    x = i % SIZE
    return x, y, z

random_tuples = [index_to_3d(i, CUBE_SIZE) for i in random.sample(range(CUBE_SIZE ** 3), SPHERES_NUMBER)]

for k in range(SPHERES_NUMBER):
    x_0, y_0, z_0 = random_tuples[k]
    plot_sphere(x_0, y_0, z_0)

mlab.show()
```

Output:

[image]

***Spheres cluster***

Let's utilize [`gauss`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.gauss) to create coordinates for the cluster points.

Code:

```
import random
from itertools import product

from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

[phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:12j, 0:np.pi:12j]
x = np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)
y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(theta)


def plot_sphere(x_0, y_0, z_0):
    r = 0.5
    return mlab.mesh(r * x + x_0, r * y + y_0, r * z + z_0)

SPHERES_NUMBER = 200

def create_cluster(CLUSTER_SIZE):
    means_and_deviations = [(1, 1.5), (1, 1.5), (1, 1.5)]
    def generate_point(means_and_deviations):
        return tuple(random.gauss(mean, deviation) for mean, deviation in means_and_deviations)
    cluster_points = set()
    while len(cluster_points) < CLUSTER_SIZE:
        cluster_points.add(generate_point(means_and_deviations))
    return list(cluster_points)

cluster_points = create_cluster(SPHERES_NUMBER)

for k in range(SPHERES_NUMBER):
    x_0, y_0, z_0 = cluster_points[k]
    plot_sphere(x_0, y_0, z_0)

mlab.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but in your case, the position randomness of the sphere has gone but I need the position randomness of spheres. It mightnot be a straight line or a square but it should choose any pattern.

Comment: Thank you but the problem still remains nither the connection nor the randomness of position was solved .

Comment: @bhaskar I believe there is a gap regarding the "randomness" definition. The spheres are at random positions from the axis. Do you mean that you want them to be not on the same line and in a different position?

Comment: Yes I don't want them in same line. They must be scattered but also they must be connected with each other having the radius constant. Example https://www.researchgate.net/figure/BA-BAM1-and-BAM2-clusters-with-1024-monomers-having-porosities-087-074-and-064_fig1_320075066

Comment: @bhaskar If they are at random positions within a square is that good? Besides what do you mean by "connected with each other"? it's not clear from the link as there is no connection there

Comment: If you can see the previous link the BA, BAM1, BAM2 structure the particles are interconnected with eachother with same radious nd the position of the particle is random not in a single line or in a square or in a circle thy are random on the 3d plane.

Comment: @bhaskar Modified go get results that are similar to what in the link above, with the same radiuses (however I see no physical connection between the spheres).

Comment: I guess you meant "touching each other" by connected, not interconnected with a line or some visible bonding line.

Comment: Thank you, almost there now all I need to think is how to connect the outer walls of the spheres with each other. as u can see for sphere number =200 in the lower and the upper side of the image there are few spheres which are completely isolated i want them to be a part of the main chain

Comment: Just adjust `r`, with `r=0.5` the walls are touching each other. @bhaskar
In BA from the given example, we see that some spheres are floating in space, just like in his simulation.

Comment: still, some sphere does not connect. all spheres should be connected

Comment: @bhaskar Added cluster based on gauss distribution, however, to achieve shapes such as you desire you have to generate the cluster in a specific shape, such as "liquid atoms" maybe something similar to Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution.